# Which color space does linear-gradient() uses?

Tags: css, colors, rgb, color-space, hsl

Which color space does CSS's linear-gradient() function uses, RGB, HSL or HSV and why ?

Can I change the color space of my own choice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In the future](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#linear-gradients) you can specify the color space

> Compared to [css3-images], this level adds a  token to customize color interpolation in gradients as described in CSS Color 4 § 12 Interpolation.

```
linear-gradient() = linear-gradient(
  [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ]? || <color-interpolation-method>,
  <color-stop-list>
)
<side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]
```

You can keep reading for more detail

---

Safari has some support for this if you want to test: https://twitter.com/argyleink/status/1490376117064065025

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a color space in the gradient function, the default space is sRGB (though [Chrome has a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1498954) where this is not quite right in MacOS).

Browsers have begun to ship [the newer syntax](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/high-definition-css-color-guide/#gradients-in-different-color-spaces), which allows you to specify the color space: `linear-gradient(in oklch 90deg, red, blue)`. Valid color spaces are `hsl`, `hwb`, `lch`, `oklch` (the polar spaces) and `srgb`, `srgb-linear`, `lab`, `oklab`, `xyz`, `xyz-d50`, and `xyz-d65` (the rectangular spaces).

As of late 2023, this syntax is supported in Chrome, Safari, and Edge, but not Firefox.